# Can Di2 only be tested as a complete setup?

Tags: shimano-di2

I'm having problem testing my Di2 setup. Long story short, I got a pair of used but in very good condition Dura Ace Di2 9070 brifters for a cheap price. I then bought a new Di2 cable set with external battery mount, external junction SM-JC40 and the SM-EW90 junction A. For the RD I bought an Ultegra R8050 RD, also in a very good condition since the shop said they just took it off a new bike. The batteries are the SM-BTR1 with around 50% charge, as indicated on the junction box when I plugged the cable into it. Currently I'm missing an FD.

Now the problem is I want to test whether the setup works out of the box without firmware update so I plugged everything in, checked the connection etc, but the shifter isn't doing anything and the RD doesn't move. Holding the shifter button also doesn't show the battery level. So my question is: Is it normal for Di2 to not work without the left shifter and FD connected? Or is it really a firmware problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need that front derailleur in a road system for it to function. Shimano have a good troubleshooting guide but you're just as easy downloading the etube software and plugging it in to the computer

Comment: I guess I won't be able to know before I buy an FD then. Problem with troubleshooting is that I have to buy the BCR2 as well, which I will in the future.

Comment: Also: the derailleurs have to be from the same family to work together.

Comment: If you aren't aware of bettershifting.com, that site may have useful information. Posting as a comment because I haven't gone through it. To my knowledge, Di2 can operate in a 1x setup. I believe it does not need to have an MTB rear derailleur to do this. I'm not certain if there are any intermediate steps involved in setting it up as a 1x.

Comment: https://road.cc/file/shimano-di2-compatibility-chartpdf

Comment: Road derailleurs have to be used front and rear both. Mountain can be used rear only. See shimano chart link.

Comment: @Weiwen Ng
I am aware of that site but unfortunately didn't find the specific information regarding this.

Comment: @JoeK
Thanks for pointing it out. I did check the chart to make sure my parts work together but didn't think about both of them having to be used together. It gave me a scare for a moment since I remember a youtuber running his bike 1x with Dura Ace Di2 shifters and they worked. But he used MTB and GRX RD, I guess that's why.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but are you sure you have all the wires pressed in firmly until you hear the little click?

Comment: @JoeK Does that mean that if your FD or left shifter connection fails in the middle of nowhere, the whole system stops working?

Comment: @Nathan Knutson i think the system is pretty proof against that, it's shimano's baby. The middle of nowhere failure is more likely to be fatigue in wires flexing over time rather than with the solid-state electronics. I have never seen an unexplained failure that wasn't related to cabling or mechanical damage. Not yet, anyway!

Comment: Have you tried updating the firmware on all components? With the correct firmware, the Di2 experience is as if all the shifters were just buttons that work with any Di2 parts but in reality firmware is needed for old parts to recognize new ones. You can update firmware by plugging in with your A-junction to a PC with E-tube Project. The program is free. Plug it in directly, not to a USB hub. I would also check the connections. Also, you said batteries, plural, are you trying to use more than one battery?

Comment: @Pisco I'm waiting for a BCR2 to arrive to update my firmware. Also nope, I have 2 external batteries but of course will only use one. Connections are all checked and clicked so there should be no problem in that end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay problem solved. Apparently the NOS cable set that I bought came with an SM-EW90-A with really old firmware. After installing E-Tube Project v3.4.5 and restarting my laptop, I was able to update the junction box using SM-BCR2. The RD works without the FD mounted and I was able to make initial adjustment while waiting for the FD.
Thank you for all your comments and hopefully we learn something new everyday!